# Why my Python program can't run correctly? It can run but don't get the result I want to

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function of the program is to compress two folders and then save them to one folder. The program can run but I get an error message exactly as follows:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe D:/Python/backup_ver1.py
'zip' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
���������ļ���

Failed backup
```

Yes, it's just as you see. I can't get more information from that.

The code is as follow:

```
import os
import time
source = ['E:\\source1','E:\\source2']
target_dir = 'E:\\target'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") +'.zip'
zip_command = 'zip -qr {0} {1}'.format(target,' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print("Successful bakup to",target)
else:
    print("Failed backup")
```

I have "source1", "source2" and "target" in my computer.

Comment: Why are you using a system call rather than using the built in zip api? https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Comment: Print out `zip_command` and run it in a shell. Does it work?

Comment: This code looks familiar - how many other people in your class are asking about this on SO today?

Comment: Is this Windows? What zip utility are you using?

Comment: You should use op.path for manipulating (e.g. joining) paths. The output looks like some control codes or a confused console. Where did you ran this program from (IDE, console, IDLE, ...)?

Comment: Well I don't care much about Windows, but if there is no zip tool, why would there be garbage displayed and not an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I use 7zip on my system, so my syntax is a little different than yours.
Try this:

```
import os
import time
source = ['d:\\source1','d:\\source2']
target_dir = 'd:\\target'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") +'.zip'
zip_command = '"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" a {0} {1}'.format(target,' '.join(source))
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print("Successful bakup to",target)
else:
    print("Failed backup")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.So friendly you are.